# I can't update my SQL database with this sentences in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm writting down a program that the user has to fill up a DataGridTable and 2 textboxes to edit a bill. The program executes the lines, but nothing happens in the Database. Even tho in the same function, if the user add more lines in the datagridtable, them are added also in the database, and that works fine, but It's the update the problem.

I've tried several types of syntaxis, but same to this that I have.

Even tho I have using the Try/catch methods, it doesn't show any kind of error or windows to tell me why it is not working. It's driving me crazy.

```
SqlDataAdapter daAdaptador2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    foreach (var Linea in Fac.lDetalles)
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                //adapter.UpdateCommand = command;
                                daAdaptador2.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand                                                                 
                                ("UPDATE factudet SET iLinea = @iLinea, iCantidad = @iCantidad, iPrecioU = @iPrecioU, " +
                                "iImporte = @iImporte, sCodigo = @sCodigo, sArticulo = @sArticulo, sDescripcion = @sDescripcion " +
                                "WHERE iNFactura = " + Fac.iNFactura + " AND iID = " + Linea.iID, cnSqlConex);

                                daAdaptador2.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iLinea", Linea.iLinea);
                                daAdaptador2.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iCantidad", Linea.iCantidad);
                                daAdaptador2.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iPrecioU", Linea.iPrecioU);
                                daAdaptador2.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iImporte", Linea.iImporte);
                                daAdaptador2.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sCodigo", Linea.sCodigo);
                                daAdaptador2.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sArticulo", Linea.sArticulo);
                                daAdaptador2.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sDescripcion", Linea.sDescripcion);


                                daAdaptador2.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                iDet++;


                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Error al editar factura" + "\n" + e.Message + e.Source + e.Data);
                            }
                        }
```

It's supposed to Update the lines in the table, but it doesn't. I use the similar syntaxis in the same version of the program but in Access, and It works just fine, I always have a lot of problems

Comment: Why do you use parameters only with `SET`, why not with `WHERE` (`WHERE  iNFactura = @iNFactura...`)? Also check you query, maybe it should not update anything because of `WHERE` condition is `false`

Comment: What do you mean? I use SET and Where at th end of the command

Comment: He means you concat the string in the `WHERE` clause instead of using parameters

Comment: How? I don't understand. I'm quite beginner in this language.

Comment: It just quietly does nothing? Then the where clause is wrong/too limiting. It is always a good idea to log out the sql syntax you create. Do that and if it isn't directly obvious, show us! - Also: Do not throw away the return value from the ExecuteNonQuery !!! It will tell you the  number of rows affected.

Comment: Roman- I'll try that and tell you if that works. TaW- Yes, it doesn't say nothing that something wrong happened, and using that red circle thing to stop the coding, the program enters that loop and reads the values correctly. Also, I have to, by superior orders, log in in the start of the program, and log out when it closes, it's not my desire to do this this way

Comment: Roman- I've tried using parameters the same as you said and it works the same, nothing happening. As an answer too for TaW, I will get the return value from ExecuteNonQuery with a message to check what's happening.

Comment: Using parameters is only for improving your code, not for fixing the issue. You should check `WHERE` condition